# jQuery & twitter Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Hoping to get a little help or direction with a couple of javascript issues. Client site will be maintained through CMS, we need to check any URL's that may be added and if it's external, launch speedBump. We do need to have some exceptions (whitelist).

We're using twitter bootstrap modal and there are some unintended results with current code.

For instance, continue button in modal closes dialog instead of passing the URL at confirmation. If the URL is declared as http, modal closes, if it is declared as www, it appends the URL to the domain (wierd). Also looking for the best way to improve/expand or add a white list for URL's that should be ignored by speedBump. I'm sure there is a much better approach than what we have.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
// FIND EXTERNAL LINKS
$.expr[":"].external = function (a) {
    // DO NOT INCLUDE THE FOLLOWING MATCHES: EMAIL LINKS, TELEPHONE LINKS, HOSTNAME
    return !a.href.match(/^mailto\:/) && !a.href.match(/^tel\:/) && a.hostname != location.hostname
};
// ADD BOOTSTRAP DATA-TOGGLE ATTRIBUTE TO THE LINKS
$('a:external').attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
// ADD BOOTSTRAP DATA-TARGET ATTRIBUTE TO THE LINKS
$('a:external').attr('data-target', '#speedbump');
// ADD EXTERNAL LINK CLASS .ext_link FOR STYLING
$("a:external").addClass("ext_link");
// ADD THE LINK AND TITLE TO THE MODAL WINDOW
$(function () {
    $('a.ext_link').click(function () {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        $('#url_link').attr('href', url);
    });
});
```

});

Current code and modal example on jsfiddle for anyone that wouldn't mind taking a look: http://jsfiddle.net/zendiko/TYAeD/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why is this happening. However, hooking redirect functionality to `show` event seems to solve the problem.

```
$('#speedbump').on('show', function () {
    $('#url_link').click(function () {
        document.location = $(this).attr('href');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mati, this does seem to resolve the issue of the modal continue button not passing the URL. Doesn't fix the issue between http and www behavior but it's a start and I appreciate the help!